# For $f \in H^1(\mathbb{T}^n)$ and some open $A \subset \mathbb{T}^n$, which space does $f \cdot \chi_{A}$ belong to?

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $\mathbb{T}^n:=(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})^n$ be the $n$-dimensional torus.

Let us fix a nonempty open set $A \subset (0,1)^n$ and define $A_p:=\cup_{ \overrightarrow{m} \in \mathbb{Z}^n} (A+\overrightarrow{m}) \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Then, $A_p$ may in fact be identified as an open subset of $\mathbb{T}^n$.

Now, consider the Sobolev space $H^1(\mathbb{T}^n)=W^{1,2}(\mathbb{T}^n)$. Then for any $f \in H^1(\mathbb{T}^n)$, I would like to find the space in which the function
\begin{equation}
\chi_{A_p}(x) \cdot f(x)
\end{equation}
belongs to. Here, $\chi_{A_p}(x)$ is the characteristic function at $A_p$.

I am tempted to say that $\chi_{A_p}(x) \cdot f(x)$ belongs $H^1(A_p)$ but what exactly is $H^1(A_p)$?

Could anyone please clarify for me?

Comment: Isn't this equivalent to askting that the restriction of $f$ to $A_p$ is in $H^1(A_p)$? This ofc depends on your definition of $H^1$.

Comment: @daw My definition of $H^1$ is standard. Weak(=distributional) derivatives exist up to the first order and they are all square-integrable.